# JSONException sendo lançada em pesquisa no Twitter - Java

Tags: java, json, twitter-api

Tenho um algoritmo que faz uma pesquisa de tweets antigos no Twitter.
A aplicação funcionou normalmente por uns dias, mas do nada começou a lançar uma exceção.

Código:

```java
public static List<Tweet> getTweets(String username, String since, String until, String querySearch) {
    List<Tweet> results = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    try {
        String refreshCursor = null;
        while (true) {              
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getURLResponse(username, since, until, querySearch, refreshCursor));
            refreshCursor = json.getString("scroll_cursor");   // <<--------
            System.out.println("while");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse((String) json.get("items_html"));
            Elements tweets = doc.select("div.js-stream-tweet");

            if (tweets.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }

            for (Element tweet : tweets) {
                String usernameTweet = tweet.select("span.username.js-action-profile-name b").text();
                String txt = tweet.select("p.js-tweet-text").text().replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "");
                int retweets = Integer.valueOf(tweet.select("span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr("data-tweet-stat-count").replaceAll(",", ""));
                int favorites = Integer.valueOf(tweet.select("span.ProfileTweet-action--favorite span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr("data-tweet-stat-count").replaceAll(",", ""));
                long dateMs = Long.valueOf(tweet.select("small.time span.js-short-timestamp").attr("data-time-ms"));
                Date date = new Date(dateMs);

                Tweet t = new Tweet(usernameTweet, txt, date, retweets, favorites);
                results.add(t);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }

    return results;
}
```

Na linha "`<<--------`" a exceção está sendo lançada. O objeto json tem o conteúdo da página retornado, por isso não sei o que está acontecendo.

Este é o método que faz a requisição da página:

```
private static String getURLResponse(String from, String since, String until, String querySearch, String scrollCursor) throws Exception {
    String appendQuery = "";
    if (from != null) {
        appendQuery += "from:"+from;
    }
    if (since != null) {
        appendQuery += " since:"+since;
    }
    if (until != null) {
        appendQuery += " until:"+until;
    }
    if (querySearch != null) {
        appendQuery += " "+querySearch;
    }

    String url = String.format("https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=%s&src=typd&scroll_cursor=%s", URLEncoder.encode(appendQuery, "UTF-8"), scrollCursor);

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Exceção try/catch:

```
twitter4j.JSONException: JSONObject["scroll_cursor"] not found.
    at twitter4j.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:390)
    at twitter4j.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:504)
    at Manager.TweetManager.getTweets(TweetManager.java:83)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

[JSON 1,](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ybdzgszz295wxh/PesquisaTwitter.txt?dl=0)
[JSON 2,](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhwm7pelgiiy60j/Pesquisa%20Twitter%202.txt?dl=0)
[JSON 3,](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1ci9ful918huof/Pesquisa%20Twitter%203.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Coloque um `e.printStackTrace();` dentro do seu `catch` e poste aqui o que é que aparece. Se possível, também coloque a `String` que é retornada pelo `getURLResponse(...)`.

Comment: Basicamente, não há nada chamado "scroll_cursor" no JSON que você baixou. Acho que seria importante você colocar na questão um exemplo do JSON baixado com o `getURLResponse(...)`.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo dar um print da string do objeto json. Só consigo ver o conteúdo em modo Debug. json.getString() exige uma string por parâmetro. Sabe qual passar?

Comment: Tenta fazer algo assim:
`String sj = getURLResponse(username, since, until, querySearch, refreshCursor);` 
`System.out.println(sj);` 
`JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sj);` e então poste na pergunta o que sai no `println`.

Comment: Deu certo. É uma string gigante, acho que não tem como eu postar ela aqui. Tem como anexar um .txt aqui no stackoverflow?

Comment: Você pode postar ela no pastebin.com e linkar aqui.

Comment: Coloquei um link do dropbox mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25548/discussion-between-roger-rubens-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 5):

O seu JSON que dá problema consiste basicamente disso:

```js
{
    "has_more_items": false,
    "items_html": "<um monte de html...>",
    "focused_refresh_interval": 30000
}
```

Ou seja, basicamente o seu código falha quando a sua pesquisa chega ao final dos resultados, pois neste caso não há um item chamado `scroll_cursor`.

Eis o que você faz então. No lugar disso:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getURLResponse(username, since, until, querySearch, refreshCursor));
refreshCursor = json.getString("scroll_cursor");   // <<--------
```

Coloque isso:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getURLResponse(username, since, until, querySearch, refreshCursor));
boolean hasMore = json.getBoolean("has_more_items"); 
refreshCursor = hasMore ? json.getString("scroll_cursor") : null;
```

E no final do laço `while`, coloque isso:

```
if (!hasMore) break;
```

E como observou o Bruno Céssar em um comentário aqui em baixo:

> No lugar do *break* poderia ser usado o próprio `hasMore`, inicia ele como `true` fora do laço, `while(hasMore)` busca os próximos tweets, já que sempre atualiza `hasMore` mesmo.

Comment: No lugar do *break* poderia ser usado o próprio *hasMore*, inicia ele como *true* fora do laço, `while(hasMore)` busca os próximos tweets, já que sempre atualiza `hasMore` mesmo.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Sim, concordo.

Comment: Funcionou por alguns instantes, mas parou de funcionar dinovo. O pouco tempo que funcionou com a sua solução notei também que não estava sendo retornado a mesma quantidade de tweets de antes, se limitando em no máximo 18. Antes de dar esse problema, dependendo da pesquisa eu conseguia recuperar até 25 mil tweets.

Comment: @RogerRubens Então vamos lá de novo... Quantos e quais tipos de JSONs você recebe? Edite a pergunta e coloque lá os diferentes tipos de JSON que você vê.

Comment: @RogerRubens Você pode postar algum caso aonde vem o "scroll_cursor"? Ou será que o twitter removeu isso? Além disso, eu suspeitaria do "focused_refresh_interval".

Comment: @VictorStafusa Pois é cara, desde quando deu o problema a primeira vez que tá acusando a não existência do "scroll_cursor". Em relação ao "focused_refresh_interval", você acha que seria um meio de bloqueio deles?

Comment: @RogerRubens Talvez. Neste caso isso é o tempo em milisegundos que você teria que esperar antes de tentar de novo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acrescentei um 'Thread.sleep (5000)' antes de cada requisição da página mas continua dando o erro. Editei a pergunta com o método que utilizo para requisição da página. Dá uma conferida.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Fiz algumas alterações e estou tendo um novo problema. Se puder me ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77532/filenotfoundexception-sendo-lan%C3%A7ada-em-pesquisa-no-twitter-java