# FileNotFoundException sendo lançada em pesquisa no Twitter - Java

Tags: java, json, exceção, algoritmo-de-busca, twitter-api

Tenho um algoritmo que faz uma pesquisa de tweets antigos no Twitter entre duas datas. Meu objetivo é retornar todos os tweets.
O código estava como na pergunta desta [postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72911/jsonexception-sendo-lan%C3%A7ada-em-pesquisa-no-twitter-java) (pode servir de parâmetro) à poucos dias atrás e estava funcionando, mas devido algumas alterações da página do Twitter comecei a ter problemas como na própria postagem anterior.

Na tentativa de resolver o problema fiz algumas mudanças, mas agora está sendo lançada outro tipo de exceção.
Uma coisa curiosa que percebi é que a cada vez que rodo o algoritmo (com os mesmos parâmetros de pesquisa), está sendo retornado um número diferente de tweets.

Hoje o código está assim:

```
public static List<Tweet> getTweets(String username, String since, String until, String querySearch) {
    List<Tweet> results = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    try {
        String refreshCursor = null;
        while (true) {

            String response = getURLResponse(username, since, until, querySearch, refreshCursor);
            System.out.println(response);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            refreshCursor = json.getString("min_position");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse((String) json.get("items_html"));
            Elements tweets = doc.select("div.js-stream-tweet");

            if (tweets.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }

            for (Element tweet : tweets) {
                String usernameTweet = tweet.select("span.username.js-action-profile-name b").text();
                String txt = tweet.select("p.js-tweet-text").text().replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "");
                int retweets = Integer.valueOf(tweet.select("span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr("data-tweet-stat-count").replaceAll(",", ""));
                int favorites = Integer.valueOf(tweet.select("span.ProfileTweet-action--favorite span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr("data-tweet-stat-count").replaceAll(",", ""));
                long dateMs = Long.valueOf(tweet.select("small.time span.js-short-timestamp").attr("data-time-ms"));
                Date date = new Date(dateMs);

                Tweet t = new Tweet(usernameTweet, txt, date, retweets, favorites);
                results.add(t);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return results;
}
```

Método que faz a requisição da página:

```
private static String getURLResponse(String from, String since, String until, String querySearch, String scrollCursor) throws Exception {
    String appendQuery = "";
    if (from != null) {
        appendQuery += "from:"+from;
    }
    if (since != null) {
        appendQuery += " since:"+since;
    }
    if (until != null) {
        appendQuery += " until:"+until;
    }
    if (querySearch != null) {
        appendQuery += " "+querySearch;
    }

    String url = String.format("https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=%s&src=typd&max_position=%s", URLEncoder.encode(appendQuery, "UTF-8"), scrollCursor);

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Exceção:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=+since%3A2014-10-08+until%3A2014-10-10+dilma&src=typd&max_position=TWEET-520341224046469121-520363066366496768-BD1UO2FFu9QAAAAAAAAETAAAAAcAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at Manager.TweetManager.getURLResponse(TweetManager.java:58)
at Manager.TweetManager.getTweets(TweetManager.java:121)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

JSON baixado: [JSON](https://www.dropbox.com/s/btkmuedrbitapm7/JSON1.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Já tentei usá-lo, mas pelo fato do Twitter4j utilizar a API do Twitter, ele me restringe a pesquisa de até 10 dias àtras além de não me retornar um número grande de tweets. No meu caso quero retornar tweets de quarquer data e quantos tiver.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?